# Notation: Writing a sum in Octave with index

Tags: sum, octave

I'm trying to make this sum:

[image]

I've tried the following where I define the function by itself and then put it in the sum brackets with the index in square brackets at the end:

```
f = @(i) dot_r(i) * qs(:,i);
q_maerke = vt_next - sum(f([1:j-1]));
```

I'm certain that I messed up somewhere since I get the correct result when I calculate the result using pencil and paper, but when I use the `sum` function in Octave it goes bad.

I've also tried the following code that is based on loops, but I'd like to have something a bit better:

```
for i = 1 : j-1 
    q_maerke = q_maerke - dot_r(i,j) * qs(:,i); 
end
```

Comment: Is `r_{ij}` a matrix and `q_i` a vector?  Given the definition in the equation and your code, they are conflicting with each other.

Comment: r_ij is a dot product of unit vector and a vector and q_i is a unit vector

Comment: If that's a unit vector then why are there two indices to access contents? Shouldn't there be just one? That's pretty confusing I will admit.

Comment: I'm implementing the gram-schmidt algorithm, in the step before this we are finding the dot products and putting these into a matrix

Comment: OK. So they're in a matrix lol. Thank you. I'll write an answer when I'm at work. Your code obviously isn't right

Comment: I got tired of the sum function and created a for loop which worked    for i = 1 : (j-1)
   q_maerke = q_maerke - dot_r(i,j) * qs(:,i);
   end
(code blocks doesnt work for me comments)

Comment: Very natural to hate loops. Now, are your unit vectors stacked by rows or by columns? What I mean is that is your matrix created where each unit vector is a single row vector or a single column vector?

Comment: The matrix is created so the unit vectors are stacked by columns

Comment: OK great. Give me about 10 minutes. About to step into work. You can do it in one line without the sum.

Comment: have you tried `q_maerke = q_maerke - sum(dot_r(1:j-1,j)*q(:,i));`